# query check if its latitude or just text on map

Tags: php, regex, google-maps, preg-match, latitude-longitude

On search, I want to check if query is latitude and longitude or just text search with PHP.

```
$query = '-122.0307642, 37.3316930';
```

latitude and longitude can have '-' in them also.

What `preg_match` pattern it will be for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will match two numbers (with or without a negative sign, separated by a comma) of the format `a.b` where `a` and `b` are digit-sequences of minimum length one.

```
(-?\d+\.\d+)\s*,\s*(-?\d+\.\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,\s*|\s+)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

This will net you two matches, which you can then cast to floats and check against lat/lng bounds.

This will also allow the two numbers to be separated by space. If you want to only allow a comma, use:

```
(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?),\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Comment: is this good? i added space before the comma too (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\s*|\s+)(?:,\s*|\s+)(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)